# Google AutoML Vision- How to call for multiple predictions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-vision, automl, google-cloud-automl

I'm creating a Firebase hosted webapp based on Google's I/O '17 presentation where Google's AutoML Vision can take a picture of a cloud and tell you what type of cloud it is based on its machine learning training.  The code I'm using only allows for one call and I think it's due to the following piece of the code:

```
     // Get only the first prediction response
        let data = response[0]['payload'];
        predictions[data[0].displayName] = data[0].classification.score;
```

From what I can tell from Google's Documentation the [0] corresponds to a annotateImageID.  The issue with the code passing 0 is that the webapp is unable to get predictions on more than one image.

Below is the whole portion of the code calling for the results to push to the webapp:

```
exports.callCustomModel = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(event => {
const file = gcsClient.bucket(event.bucket).file(event.name);
let destination = '/tmp/' + event.name.replace(/\s/g, '');
return file.download({destination: destination})
    .then(() => {
        if(sizeOf(destination).width > 600) {
            console.log('scaling image down...');
            return resizeImg(destination);
        } else {
            return destination;
        }     
    })
    .then(() => {
        let bitmap = fs.readFileSync(destination);
        let data = new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');
        return callAutoMLAPI(data);  
    })
    .then((response) => {
        let predictions = {};

        // Get only the first prediction response
        let data = response[0]['payload'];
        predictions[data[0].displayName] = data[0].classification.score;

        if (Object.keys(predictions).length === 0) {
            predictions = {"predictionErr": "No high confidence predictions found"};
        }
        return db.collection('images').doc(event.name).set(predictions);
    })
    .then(() => {
        // Delete tmp image file to clean up resources
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fs.unlinkSync(destination, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
            });
        });
    })
```

Comment: You may also find answer to this quesiton relevant:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173867/automl-image-prediction-problems

Answer (score 0):

`response.payload` having all the predictions above your threshold sets.